# Undefined reference to cv::Mat::Mat()

Tags: c++, opencv, g++

I made a simple c++ code that reads the webcam image and display it. However, when I compile, I get the error - 'Undefined reference to cv::Mat::Mat()'. I don't know why it shows two Mat's. Here is my code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);

    if (!cap.isOpened){
        std::cout << "Error opening camera" << std::endl;
    }

    cv::Mat img;
    
    while(1){
        cap >> img;
        cv::imshow("output", img);
        cv::waitKey(1);
    }
}
```

This is how I compile it

```
g++ example.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv4`
```

I can't figure out why the error shows up. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `cv::Mat::Mat()` looks like a default (zero-argument) constructor of class `Mat` embedded in namespace `cv`. You use it at least in the line `cv::Mat img;`. You need to link an appropriate OpenCV library to fix this linker error.

Comment: Also, you `#include` opencv2, but link against `opencv4`.

Comment: `cap.isOpened` is a function, not a variable.

Comment: Okay so it is a linking issue? I tried to link opencv2 but it was throwing an error saying opencv2.pc was not found. And yeah it should be `cap.isOpened()`, forgot the brackets here. Also, it was not showing unreferenced error for other openCV functions like videoCapture or imshow(), which was why I thought it might not be linking related

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works on my Linux:

```
g++ main.cpp -I/usr/include/opencv4/ -lopencv_core -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_highgui
```

While this is not portable, (using `cmake` would do the trick, but you'd need to learn cmake first), I'll give you a hint how you can discover this yourself.

Whenever you see an error like `Undefined reference to cv::Mat::Mat()`, go to the documentation at https://docs.opencv.org/ , chose the newest version (here: https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/ ), enter, in the "search" window, the name of a class/function the linker cannot find  (here: `Mat`), read the header that defines it (here: `#include<opencv2/core/mat.hpp>`), then the missing  library will have the name `libopencv_core.*` or `libopencv_mat.*`. Find whichever is in your machine (e.g. inside `/user/lib`) and link it, omitting the extension and the beginning `lib` in the name. In my case the library location, with the full path, is `/usr/lib/libopencv_core.so`, so I link it with `-lopencv_core`. Then you need to find the remaining libs in the same way.

Learn how to automatize this, e.g. via a `Makefile`, `CMakeLists.txt` or just a simple bash script.